# Remove option when class is added

Tags: jquery

So I have a configurable product in a shop and depending on the option you have chosen, the price is changing. When you have chosen an option besides the option "Choose option" it should disappear. For example when you want the product with 1400 mm but changed your mind, the option "Choose option" should disappear. I didnt quiet managed to do that. Maybe you could help. My fiddle is down here:

https://jsfiddle.net/f19L73wu

I suppose you could say that when the class "selected" is added to an option, it should make the first option value disappear.

```
    <div class="input-box">
    <select name="super_attribute[149]" id="attribute149" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
        <option value="">Choose option…</option>
        <option value="28" price="139" data-label="1000 mm">1000 mm</option>
        <option value="30" price="169" data-label="1200 mm" class="selected">1200 mm</option>
        <option value="32" price="199" data-label="1400 mm">1400 mm</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: so you want that user can select only one time and then select-box have to disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the first option using:

```
jQuery('select').one('change', function(){
    jQuery(this).find('option').first().remove();
});
```

> Note that you want to do this only on the first change.

Another option - use css for that:

```
jQuery('select').change(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

css:

```
select.selected option:first {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for removing option.

```
$(".super-attribute-select > option").each(function(){

   if($(this).attr('class') == 'Your class which you have assigned'){
        $(this).remove();
   }

});
```

But I think this is not the good way that you can assign class to options, in my point of view you can just check values for deletion like this.

```
    $(".super-attribute-select option[value='your-val']").each(function() {
       $(this).remove();
    });
```